# git repository in local machine to access from laptop

Tags: git, version-control, repository, push, pull

I would like to have the following setup to work with git: for a given project I would like to have my "origin" repository in a directory of my desktop computer at work ($desktop). Then I would like to be able to access, pull and push from this repository from home or anywhere else ($laptop).

For what I have seen in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412562/setting-up-git-repository-on-local-machine) the process would normally involve creating a bare git repository in my desktop using

```
$desktop > git init -bare
```

However my understanding is that this would produce a repository without a working directory. I don't want this. I want my repository to be project specific, to be located in a given directory in both my desktop and laptop and to keep track only of stuff that I keep in a given directory tree. This is apparently problematic with git and that one should "never" push into a normal repository.

Is there a way of sorting this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to simply pull from your normal repository on your desktop, but rather than pushing directly to the checked-out branch there, push to some other branch that is only for receiving updates on your laptop, and then merge them separately.

That is:

```
laptop$ git clone desktop:path/to/project
laptop$ cd project
[... make changes...]
laptop$ git push -f desktop:path/to/project master:from-laptop

desktop$ cd path/to/project
desktop$ git merge from-laptop
```

You can configure `branch.master.push master:from-laptop` in your laptop repository so that `git push` will push according to that spec by default.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that it's not recommended to push to a repository with a check-out; that's because the push won't update the checked out files so the state of the repository can very easily become confusing.

One easy way to work around that is to create two repositories on your desktop: one bare one that you can push to from your laptop, and a working repo that you use when you want to code on the desktop.  Another way is to make your laptop repository visible from your desktop, so you can pull in both directions.

Note that even if you're pushing to a bare repository, there's nothing stopping you from pulling from your working repository first -- so you can always be up-to-date with what you were doing on your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

On your desktop repository, you need to add in your .git/config:

```
[core]
   sharedRepository true

[receive]
   denyCurrentBranch false
```

The first config allows you to push to the repository, the second one allows you to push on the branch the remote repository is checked out.

Hope this help !